# Find the constrained least-squares estimator for a multiple regression model

Tags: optimization, linear-regression

Consider the multiple regression model

$$Y=X\beta+\epsilon$$

with the restriction that $\sum_l^n b_i=1$.

I want to find the least squares estimator of $\beta$, so I need to solve the following optimization problem

$$ min (Y-X\beta)^t(Y-X\beta) $$

$$s.t. \sum_l^n b_i=1$$

Let's set

$$L=(Y-X\beta)^t(Y-X\beta)-\lambda(U^t\beta-1)=Y^tY+\beta^tX^tX\beta+-2\beta^tX^tY-\lambda(U^t\beta-1)$$
where U is a dummy vector of ones (and therefore $U^T\beta=\sum_l^n b_i$).

Take derivatives

$\frac{d}{d\beta}=2X^tX\beta-2X^tY-\lambda U^t=0$

$\frac{d}{d\lambda}=U^t\beta-1=0$

So from the first equation we can get an expression for $\beta$, but what should I do with the $\lambda$? The second equation doesn't seem to be useful to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, i think in the first derivative the $U^t$ should be corrected by $U$.

The two derivatives can be written as a linear systems of equations as:

\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
2X^tX& -1\\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\beta\\
\lambda
\end{matrix}
\right]=\left[
\begin{matrix}
2X^tY\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right].
\end{equation}

Solving these equations could lead to the solutions.